# Angular 5 - Directive ngClass and ngStyle innerHTML

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to dynamically change a directive style/class.  For some reason angular is not creating the binding when I change the innerHTML with ngStyle or ngClass.  Eventually what I would like to do is wherever I place this directive I want the background color to update based on a service variable.  For simplicity sakes, I created an example that is not even rendering my hard coded ngStyle background-color.

In the example I have a simple directive that does this that I'm loading on the app component. I don't understand why this line doesn't make the background color green.

```
  this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = `<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'green'}"> BG Color should be green. But its not.  `;
```

Here is the stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcgnmh

What am I missing? Or is there a better way to be able to do this? I have tried using outputs, looked at event emitters but they havent helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `@HostBinding`. Working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzngy5?file=app/bgcolor.directive.ts. Random blog post on the subject [here](https://alligator.io/angular/hostbinding-hostlistener/).

Used like:

```
@HostBinding('style.background-color') color: string = 'green';
```

More info:

I don't believe angular is aware of manual `innerHTML` changes. What I think you're trying to do, is create a custom directive that, itself, automatically adds and configures an `ngStyle` directive. While this is possible, it's not super easy to do currently (there's at least one open issue about it, though I can't immediately find it). A larger issue is I think your implementation strategy would cause problems if you ever added both a stand alone `ngStyle` directive to a component, as well as your custom directive. It's also just a huge overkill compared to the proper, host binding solution.

Also, as an FYI: in angular you should always avoid using `ElementRef` directly. It can cause problems when you use ahead of time compilation or server side rendering or a host of other technologies that don't execute in the browser. Angular is also not aware of those changes (in addition to host binding, another even "lower level" way of manually updating the element's style without resorting to `ElementRef` is to use the [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) or, soon, renderer3. These methods are SSR friendly).

Comment: Hey thanks for the information. If I was to go down this route, how would I make this to bind a value to a service. Here is updated link to what Im attempting to do.  I want to be able to use this directive throughout my whole app and have the value change when my service value changes. 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnqdzt?file=app/bgcolor.directive.ts

Comment: Looking at your code, I think there's more that you don't know then you realize. I highly recommend you familiarize yourself with observables, as they'll solve this particular problem of yours, and that you work through the basic tutorials at angular.io. Here's a working version of your project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtmfav?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Your basic problem is that `this.color = this.testService.backgroundColor` executes once and once only, during directive initialization. If, later, `this.testService.backgroundColor` is updated to a new value, `this.color` does not automatically get updated. JavaScript doesn't work this way. Hence you need observables.

Comment: I should also say, by "familiarize yourself with observables," I really just mean go through the tutorials at angular.io. There's a lot to learn regarding observables, and it can be overwhelming. You don't need to know much. I still don't think I know very much. Angular.io should set you on the right path tho.

Comment: Hey Thanks. I knew why my example wasn't working, but I didn't know the proper way to go about it.  I know the basics of observables, as I use them mainly for http requests, however for instances like this, I havent used them much.  You're right they are complex, but very powerful. Ill definitely go through more tutorials and try to understand it better.  This example that you did really helps me a lot. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: If you need to create your own observable to store a value, (not including something like `of()` or `timer()`), using either `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` is the way to go. `BehaviorSubject` is created with a starting value, will always remember its "current value", and anything that subscribes to it also immediately receives whatever the current value is. `Subject` does not have a starting value, does not have a "current value", and anything that subscribes to it only receives a value when a new value is emitted..